# Struts2 Validatation

Tags: struts2

I have used `Struts2` in a period time, but I am still very confused with `Struts2` Validation.

I have used xml-validation, or method `addFieldError()` to validate, but when I first come to input form-page, a page with struts-tags, and a `<s:form>`, I can not just go to this page by a href-link, I must go through another action, I read that page jsp with struts-tags must come from a action.

And I usually create a Action just for redirect to this input page, in `execute()` method just "success" and the role of this action is to go to input page legally, and in action which process the input form input-page, I choose the "input" result is still this input page.

So, I feel uncomfortable to do this, I always have a `GoToSiteAction`, just first-time go to input page.

So, I really need your help!!.

Comment: that is standard way since S2 need to init a number of component in order to work correctly and request shd come through the s2 Dispatcher filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using or not using the struts2-conventions plugin to it's full effect. Please see: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/convention-plugin.html search this page for the string "Examples of Action and Result to Template mapping" and consider the table which follows.

In the future after adding the struts2-conventions-plugin jar to your project add the postfix "-input" to the end of all future forms.

Say we created a form to add a new employee:

```
/WEB-INF/content/add-employee-input.jsp
```

The struts2 form tag would reference an action simply called "add-employee" in a java class probably named something like `com.mypackages.struts2.AddEmployee` then if the add-employee action validation fails then "input" is returned and the "add-employee-input" form is again rendered. However we do not need to create a "add-employee-input" action, the conventions plugin will do this for us automatically... as such we can directly enter the form if we wish by referencing it and this is very convenient.

Try it out and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: yes, thank you for replying. but i still place the input.jsp in the result "input" for AddEmloyee Action to call back, if validation is error and if i go to this input site the first time, i see the some error field (such as : user name is blank..., because the input site is processed by AddEmployee Action)

Comment: @user1348567 Then your action is written incorrectly--the `input` result should not have validation applied to it, the `input` action method is one of the methods skipped by the validation interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

Use the  with input fields , create a action and create a validation xml file with same name as java file name
For example : AddInput.java
xml file: AddInput-validation.xml
put it in same package.

write all the validations you need for the form in xml file like this.

```
<field name="U_Id"> 
    <field-validator type="requiredstring" short-circuit="true">
     <message>Affiliate Id cannot be empty</message> 
    </field-validator>
</field>
<field name="Password">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring" short-circuit="true">
     <message>Password cannot be empty</message> 
    </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="stringlength">  
<param name="minLength">5</param>  
<param name="maxLength">30</param>  
<message>Password cannot be less than 5 or more than 30</message>  
</field-validator>
</field>
```

When you hit the action it will first hit the validation xml and check for the validation then process the action class part.